# DevExpress TextEdit RegEx MaskType not limiting length

Tags: c#, devexpress

I intend to have a `TextEdit` that can have a maximum *4 digit length positive number*.

I use the following `TextEdit`:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Name="txtNumber" Mask="\d+{0,4}" MaskType="RegEx" />
```

I can put exactly *10 digits* in it without any sign of overflow. After that I can put more numbers, the `TextEdit` turns red but keeps letting me to add more digits.

What should I use to stop the user at 4 digits without using some code-behind magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numeric mask type](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498) with `####;` as mask:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Name="txtNumber" Mask="####;" MaskType="Numeric"/>
```

Comment: It is crucial to have only _positive numbers_. Your solution allows negative numbers.

Comment: @Nestor OK, just add `;` symbol to the end of mask.

Comment: Yes, I have found that as well :) Thanks for the tip, I'll accept the answer.